# Get running apps package?

Tags: android, package

How do I get the package of running apps? I have managed to get the names, but can't find how to get package. Here's my code.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List list = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator iter = list.iterator();
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
      ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(iter.next());
      try {
        CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        Log.w("APPS", c.toString());
      }catch(Exception e) { }
    }catch(Exception e) { }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process can contain running components from several packages, see field [pkgList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#pkgList) in RunningAppProcessInfo class.